# Piping a script to the shell to avoid a lock

Tags: bash, pipe

I've seen more and more setup instructions for projects involving a `wget` or `curl` where the output is piped to the shell. I think the first time I had seen it was with NVM.

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash`

So this seemed like a easy solution to some issues I ran into (file locks and permissions) to pipe the script file to bash instead.

`cat script.sh | bash`

Bash not being my first language I wanted to know if this was verboten or if there were better means of solving my problem.

(my script pulls the latest from a git repo, and replaces it's self and in the process. Or at least it should, but because of the lock on the script that is executing, it can't. Otherwise, replacing the file wipes the +x flag so this solution checks all the boxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your problem lies somewhere else. There is no lock on the script to change itself.

For example, you can create two scripts `a.sh` and `b.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# a.sh
cp a.sh tmp.sh
cp b.sh a.sh
mv tmp.sh b.sh
echo A
```

```
#!/bin/sh
# b.sh
cp a.sh tmp.sh
cp b.sh a.sh
mv tmp.sh b.sh
echo B
```

And now you can do magic:

```
$ a.sh
A
$ a.sh
B
$ a.sh
A
```

Execution flags are not lost in this scenario.

The only advantage of piping script into `bash` is if the command creates a script and you do not want to store that script into an actual file. In the example with `curl` it downloads an `install.sh` and immediately executes it. Without piping that would be three lines:

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh >tmp.sh
$ bash tmp.sh
$ rm tmp.sh
```

The piping from `cat`

```
$ cat script.sh | bash
```

is not functionally different from a simple `bash script.sh`.

Comment: Except for the value of `$0`; `bash script.sh` sets `$0` to `script.sh` but `cat script.sh | bash` sets `$0` to `bash`.

Comment: I think git is replacing the script when it pulls updates to the file. Because of that the permissions do not survive. There are some way to "check in the permissions" though that ends up being more steps.